# Is there any way to send messages to channels without replying?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

With Discord switching to application commands, bots have no way to send messages without replying to a command a user has sent. I would like to know if this is true?

Answer (score 1):

For sending messages without replying in discord.js v14, you can use this code:

```
client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  await interaction.channel.send("Lorem Ipsum")
});
```

Comment: Take this as a note that it returns an "interaction did not respond" so it's better to reply.